# Can't connect to Database via SSH with Nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, ssh, dbeaver

I try to connect my node.js backend with my mysql database running on Debian server.
With Dbeaver everything works finde. Connection with SSH and my database with username and password.
Now I try to connect with my Application via SSH and I get the following error:

```
Error: All configured authentication methods failed
```

The credentials are exactly the same like in Dbeaver.

This is my code:

```
   const mysql = require('mysql2');
const { Client } = require('ssh2');
const sshClient = new Client();
const dbServer = {
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    port: process.env.DB_PORT,
    user: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_DATABASE
}
const tunnelConfig = {
    host: process.env.DB_SSH_HOST,
    port: 22,
    username: process.env.DB_SSH_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_SSH_PASSWORD
}
const forwardConfig = {
    srcHost: '127.0.0.1',
    srcPort: 3306,
    dstHost: dbServer.host,
    dstPort: dbServer.port
};
const SSHConnection = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log(dbServer);
    console.log(tunnelConfig);
    console.log(forwardConfig)
    sshClient.on('ready', () => {
        sshClient.forwardOut(
        forwardConfig.srcHost,
        forwardConfig.srcPort,
        forwardConfig.dstHost,
        forwardConfig.dstPort,
        (err, stream) => {
             if (err) reject(err);
             const updatedDbServer = {
                 ...dbServer,
                 stream
            };
            console.log(updatedDbServer)
            const connection =  mysql.createConnection(updatedDbServer);
           connection.connect((error) => {
            if (error) {
                reject(error);
            }
            resolve(connection);
            });
        });
    }).connect(tunnelConfig);
});
```

Do you have any suggestions?
Thank you very much!